# PHP saves broken image files downloaded from a URL

Tags: php, copy, fopen, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

No matter which function I'm using:

```
copy("http:" . $imglink, "images/" . substr($imglink, 34));
//or
file_put_contents("images/" . substr($imglink, 34), file_get_contents("http:" . $imglink));
//or
file_put_contents("images/" . $productData['imagefile'], fopen($productData['imagelink'], 'r'));
```

the files are saved broken and almost 4 times bigger. No errors in the log, 
already checked that I can manually download healthy images from the remote server through the browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - the image filename contains space char which should be 
 `rawurlencode($imglink)`-ed before it is passed as argument